# How work with OnExpiry in jquery with ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery

I need to expire the reservations after 24hrs from the booking time; I have the script as:

```
$('#expire').countdown({
    until: new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>"),
    format: 'dHMS',
    layout:'{hnn}:'+'{mnn}:'+'{snn}',
    onExpiry: liftOff(),
    expiryText:"Expired"
});
```

Here's the function which redirects to trips/expire controller with the reservation id:

```
function liftOff(){ 

    var reservation_id = $("#reservation_id").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('trips/expire'); ?>",
        async: true,
        data: "reservation_id="+reservation_id,
        success: function(data){    
            location.reload(true);
        }
    });

}
```

The timer runs for specified hours, but it does not redirect to that page. The format comes as 00 : 00 : 00. I get the reservation id in the script.

What is the problem with my hint?

Any help please....!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your `liftOff` function is redirecting. You're doing an AJAX POST to the trips/expire URL, and then on the success of the post, you're reloading the current page.

Rather than doing an AJAX POST, you could simply do a `window.location` redirect and pass the `reservation_id` value through as a query string parameter.

Comment: Thanks Scrooby. You mean to say i need to change the "location.reload(true);" to "window.location = 'http://sitname.com/trips/expire'.reservation_id" ?

Comment: I would suggest you remove the `$.ajax` code block and replace it with `window.location = "/trips/expire/?reservation_id=" + reservation_id`